# Analisis de vulnerabilidad en Fortify

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline, devops, integración-continua

tengo la siguiente porción de código de mi pipeline el cual hace el análisis en Fortify:

```
container('Fortify') {
  scanFortify {
    routeScan: "src/.java"
    nameProject: env.nameProject
  }
}
```

un ejemplo de cómo funciona la ejecución:

Si el pipeline va por la ejecución numero 10 me crea una versión 10 en Fortify y así sucesivamente, lo que pasa es que me está dando una alerta de una vulnerabilidad que necesito que omita en este caso es una vulnerabilidad de cifrado CBC Cipher, hay alguna forma de decirle al pipeline que omita esta regla en especifico